# Scraping a large database using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy, pymongo

My project requires me to scrape the database of myfitnesspal,how would i scrape the nutrition info of certain foods using the search option?

Basically how do i navigate through a search form on scrapy

Comment: did you manage to scrap any data from mfp ?

Answer (score 1):

read some **Scrapy tutorials** first:

- http://scrapy.org/
- http://lxml.de/
- http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/
- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/

these will probably help you :)